# bazel unable to build typescript locally on windows

Tags: typescript, bazel, bazel-aspect

I have created a projectB to experiment ts build with bazel.

[image]
Here is my BUILD file

```
load("@aspect_rules_ts//ts:defs.bzl", "ts_project")

ts_project(
    name = "ts",
    srcs = ["say-hello.ts"],
)
```

- I have pass Windows 10 to dev mode as required (it fixed a first issue)
- I have installed MSYS2

But I am stuck with this error now and I don't understand how to dig it:

```
> bazel build //packages/projectB:ts --enable_runfiles=true --verbose_failures

DEBUG: C:/users/xxx/_bazel_xxx/vwrfujim/external/aspect_rules_ts/ts/private/ts_project.bzl:74:14:
WARNING: disabling ts_project workers which are not currently support on Windows hosts.
See https://github.com/aspect-build/rules_ts/issues/228 for more details.
INFO: Analyzed target //packages/projectB:ts (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: C:/_ws/bench-monorepo-bazel/packages/projectB/BUILD:3:11: TsValidateOptions packages/projectB/_validate_ts_options.optionsvalid.d.ts failed: (Exit 1): validator.bat failed: error executing command
  cd /d C:/users/xxx/_bazel_xxx/vwrfujim/execroot/bazel-ts-monorepo
  SET BAZEL_BINDIR=bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin
  bazel-out\x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6\bin\external\npm_typescript\validator.bat packages/projectB/tsconfig.json packages/projectB/_validate_ts_options.optionsvalid.d.ts //packages/projectB:ts {"allow_js":false,"composite":fa
lse,"declaration":false,"declaration_map":false,"emit_declaration_only":false,"incremental":false,"preserve_jsx":false,"resolve_json_module":false,"source_map":false,"ts_build_info_file":""}
# Configuration: 6b3a78fd68b654d0c65adba690b428378aa67d1bae3efe12a73a2a2a46d4d97d
# Execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host
Target //packages/projectB:ts failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.859s, Critical Path: 0.89s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I even tried to run the batch validator.bat, and I got this, but I'm not sure this is the actuel error... Maybe I'm invoking the command the wrong way:

```
PS C:\_WS\bench-monorepo-bazel> bazel-out\x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6\bin\external\npm_typescript\validator.bat packages/projectB/tsconfig.json packages/projectB/_validate_ts_options.optionsvalid.d.ts //packages/projectB:ts {"
allow_js":false,"composite":false,"declaration":false,"declaration_map":false,"emit_declaration_only":false,"incremental":false,"preserve_jsx":false,"resolve_json_module":false,"source_map":false,"ts_build_info_file":""}        
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 206
+ ... ns.optionsvalid.d.ts //packages/projectB:ts {"allow_js":false,"compos ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
Jeton inattendu « :false » dans l’expression ou l’instruction.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 212
+ ... s.optionsvalid.d.ts //packages/projectB:ts {"allow_js":false,"composi ...
+                                                                 ~
Argument manquant dans la liste de paramètres.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```